# Centrar texto de las celdas de una columna

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla que contiene títulos de películas y las fechas de estreno.

Quiero centrar las fechas de estreno, pero quiero hacerlo en el `CSS` y no en el código `HTML`. En el `CSS` tengo puesta la propiedad `text-align: left` para que alinee tanto título como fecha de estreno a la izquierda, pero no se cómo poner que alinee a la izquierda sólo el título y centrar las fechas de estreno, por eso en el `HTML` le pongo a cada celda `style="text-align: center`"

Este es mi código

```css
.tabla
{
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    /*margin-right: 10px;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.peliculas
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.peliculas th, .peliculas td
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabla">
    <table class="peliculas">
        <th width="70%">Título</th>
        <th>Fecha estreno</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Death race</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">03/10/2008</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Desmadre de padre</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">31/08/2012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Despierto</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">28/03/2008</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Destino oculto</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">04/03/2011</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

¿Cómo lo hago sólo en `CSS`?

También me gustaría aplicarle un ancho determinado a una columna, en el `HTML` tengo puesto `th width="70%"`, cómo pongo eso mismo en el `CSS`?

Esta tabla contiene ahora mismo más de 600 registros. Para mostrar todos los registros en una página hay otra forma mejor de hacerlo en lugar de con una tabla? La web se tiene que adaptar posteriormente a dispositivos móviles, hay otro método mejor que la tabla para mostrar los resultados?

Gracias

Comment: Has probado `bootstrap`? Te ahorra muchísimo tiempo en la maquetación del front end. Para el manejo de tablas puedes usar `data-tables`. En la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/?) de `bootstrap` y en [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) encuentras toda la información respecto al manejo de tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Para alinear a la izquierda únicamente los títulos, podrías añadir una clase al `th` del titulo y aplicar los estilos a esa clase.

Ej:

html-code

```
<th class="titulo_pelicula" width="70%">Título</th>
```

css-code

```
.titulo_pelicula {/*se pondrán a la izquierda solo la columna esa.*/
    text-align: left;
}
```

Y para darle anchura a una celda determinada, podrías hacer con `jQuery` o `Javascript` recorrer los hijos de `tBody` y asignarles algún id y asignar los estilos con `JQuery`.

Ej:

```
$('element-2').css('width', '40%');
```

Y con lo de mostrar tantos resultados en una misma tabla no es recomendable, puedes hacer algún paginate, te recomiendo [éste](https://pagination.js.org/).

Como una mejora, he metido el código en sus respectivas etiquetas, las tablas digo.

```css
.tabla {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 70%;
  /*margin-right: 10px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  background: #ddd;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.peliculas {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.peliculas th,
.peliculas td {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.titulo_pelicula {
  text-align: left;
}

.fecha_estreno {
  /*Ni haría falta ya que por defecto lo centra solo*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabla">
  <table class="peliculas">
    <thead>
      <th class="titulo_pelicula" width="70%">Título</th>
      <th class="fecha_estreno">Fecha estreno</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Death race</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">03/10/2008</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Desmadre de padre</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">31/08/2012</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Despierto</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">28/03/2008</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Destino oculto</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">04/03/2011</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo usando `bootstrap` y `dataTables` por si te interesa conocer como funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Título</th>
                <th>Fecha estreno</th>
                <th>Columna1</th>
                <th>Columna2</th>
                <th>Columna3</th>
                <th>Columna4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Death race</td>
                <td>03/10/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Desmadre de padre</td>
                <td>31/08/2012</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Despierto</td>
                <td>28/03/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Destino oculto</td>
                <td>04/03/2011</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Death race 2</td>
                <td>03/10/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Desmadre de padre 2</td>
                <td>31/08/2012</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Despierto 2</td>
                <td>28/03/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Destino oculto 2</td>
                <td>04/03/2011</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Death race 3</td>
                <td>03/10/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Desmadre de padre 3</td>
                <td>31/08/2012</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Despierto 3</td>
                <td>28/03/2008</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Destino oculto 3</td>
                <td>04/03/2011</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Título</th>
                <th>Fecha estreno</th>
                <th>Columna1</th>
                <th>Columna2</th>
                <th>Columna3</th>
                <th>Columna4</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Utilizar frameworks y plugins tiene muchas ventajas, ya que traen funciones incorporadas que puede tomar un buen tiempo desarrollarlas desde cero, solo debes incluir las dependencias apropiadas para cada caso.

Por ejemplo, si quieres que tu tabla se vea bien en dispositivos móviles, basta con agregar la clase `table-responsive` de `bootstrap` a tu tabla y se agrega una barra de desplazamiento horizontal al final.

`bootstrap` por ejemplo te ayuda con la maquetación y los estilos en el front end y `dataTables` trae funciones como paginación, filtros de búsqueda, capacidad de seleccionar la cantidad de registros a mostrar por página, ordenar por encabezado...

[Documentación de datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

[Documentación de bootstrap tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/?)